# Vertical JavaScript Menu - Not All Subsections Displaying

Tags: javascript, css

Currently, I'm helping to build a website for a family member as part of a modeling club they have.
The website is at  http://testindyamps.weebly.com/ .

It's a website on a host that utilizes various templates for themes (I haven't had much help so far from people on said site).

I'm not 100% sure if this ist he best place to post the question, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

The main issue is that it's utilizing a sidebar navigation where when you click the menus, it expands downward to show the subpages. In this case, not all the subpages are showing. (For example, clicking on "Articles" and then "Books" shows only the first few of a dozen or so pages.

I've tried editing the JS code itself, which so far has had no affect. I've tried editing some of the CSS, however, it doesn't seem to have an affect either.

If it helps, I can share osme of the CSS code or JS code for the site itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

UPDATE: Added the code as requested.
Update 2: Added HTML: fixed to correct URL (using a test site instead of the "actual" site for the navigation).

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // Mobile sidebars
  $.fn.expandableSidebar = function(expandedClass) {
    var $me = this;

    $me.on('click', function() {
      if(!$me.hasClass(expandedClass)) {
        $me.addClass(expandedClass);
      } else {
        $me.removeClass(expandedClass);
      }
    });
  }

  // Interval loop
  $.fn.intervalLoop = function(condition, action, duration, limit) {
    var counter = 0;
    var looper = setInterval(function(){
      if (counter >= limit || $.fn.checkIfElementExists(condition)) {
        clearInterval(looper);
      } else {
        action();
        counter++;
      }
    }, duration);
  }

  // Check if element exists
  $.fn.checkIfElementExists = function(selector) {
    return $(selector).length;
  }

  // Check if desktop display

  $.fn.isDesktop = function() {
    return $(window).width() > 1024;
  }

  var briskController = {
    init: function(opts) {
      var base = this;

      base._addClasses();

      setTimeout(function(){
        base._attachEvents();
      }, 1000);
    },

    _addClasses: function() {
      var base = this;

      // Add fade in class to nav + logo + banner
      $('body').addClass('fade-in');

      // Keep subnav open if submenu item is active
      $('.sidebar-nav .active').parents('.has-submenu').children('.dropdown').addClass('open');

      // Add placeholder text to inputs
      $('.wsite-form-sublabel').each(function(){
        var sublabel = $(this).text();
        $(this).prev('.wsite-form-input').attr('placeholder', sublabel);
      });
    },

    _cloneLogin: function() {
      var loginDetach = $('#member-login').clone(true);
      $('.mobile-nav .wsite-menu-default > li:last-child').after(loginDetach);
    },

    _stickyNav: function() {
      var sticky,
          collapse,
          uncollapse,
          desktopsticky = $('body.nav-position-top.sticky-nav-on:not(.wsite-checkout-page):not(.wsite-native-mobile-editor), body.nav-position-top-right.sticky-nav-on:not(.wsite-checkout-page):not(.wsite-native-mobile-editor)').length,
          mobilesticky = $('body.sticky-nav-on:not(.wsite-checkout-page):not(.wsite-native-mobile-editor)').length;

      var stickyInit = function() {
        if (!$.fn.isDesktop() || desktopsticky) {
          // Add sticky desktop nav
          sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
            element: $('.header')[0]
          });
        }
        if ($.fn.isDesktop() && desktopsticky) {
          // Collapse header on scroll
          collapse = new Waypoint({
            element: $('body.nav-position-top.sticky-nav-on:not(.wsite-checkout-page):not(.wsite-native-mobile-editor)')[0],
            handler: function(direction) {
              $('body').addClass('collapse');
            },
            offset: -10
          });
          uncollapse = new Waypoint({
            element: $('body.nav-position-top'),
            handler: function(direction) {
              $('body').removeClass('collapse');
            },
            offset: -5
          });
        }
      }

      stickyInit();

      $(window).resize(function() {
        if (sticky) { sticky.destroy() }
        if (collapse) { collapse.destroy() }
        if (uncollapse) { uncollapse.destroy() }
        stickyInit();
      });
    },

    _sidebarNav: function() {

      // Fixed sidebar nav unless menu height exceeds viewport height
      var sidebarCheck = function() {
        if ($.fn.isDesktop() && $('body').hasClass('sticky-nav-on') && $('.header .container').height() + $('.header .contact').height() <= $(window).height() - 45) {
          $('body.nav-position-sidebar .header').addClass('stuck');
        }
        else {
          $('body.nav-position-sidebar .header').removeClass('stuck');
        }
      }

      sidebarCheck();

      $(window).resize(function() {
        sidebarCheck();
      });
    },

    _sidebarCart: function(){
      $('#wsite-mini-cart').addClass('cart-init');

      $('.wsite-nav-cart a').click(function() {
        $('.cart-init').toggleClass('cart-visible');
      });

      $('.wrapper, .header').click(function() {
        $('.cart-init').removeClass('cart-visible');
      });
    },

    _attachEvents: function() {
     var base = this;
        // Hamburger nav toggle
        $('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
        });

        // Initialize sticky nav
        base._stickyNav();

        // Initialize sidebar nav
        base._sidebarNav();

       // Copy login
        $.fn.intervalLoop('.mobile-nav #member-login', base._cloneLogin, 800, 5);

        // Subnav toggle
        $('li.has-submenu span.icon-caret, .dropdown-link').on('click', function() {
            var $me = $(this);
            if ($me.parent().hasClass('open')) {
              $me.parent().removeClass('open');
              $me.find('.open').removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              $('.open').removeClass('open');
              $me.parents('.has-submenu').children('.dropdown').addClass('open');
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
              base._sidebarNav();
            }, 800);
        });

      // Sidebar Cart Link
      $.fn.intervalLoop('.cart-init', base._sidebarCart, 1000, 5);

      // Store category dropdown
      $('.wsite-com-sidebar').expandableSidebar('sidebar-expanded');

      // Search filters dropdown
      $('#wsite-search-sidebar').expandableSidebar('sidebar-expanded');

     // Init fancybox swipe on mobile
      if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
        $('body').on('click', 'a.w-fancybox', function() {
          base._initSwipeGallery();
        });
      }
    },

    _initSwipeGallery: function() {
      var base = this;

      setTimeout(function(){
        var touchGallery = document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox-wrap')[0];
        var mc = new Hammer(touchGallery);
        mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
          if (ev.type == "panleft") {
            $("a.fancybox-next").trigger("click");
          } else if (ev.type == "panright") {
            $("a.fancybox-prev").trigger("click");
          }
          base._initSwipeGallery();
        });
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
   briskController.init();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Header */

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: @fill;
  background: @bg;
  border-bottom: 1px solid fade(@fill, 5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 12;

  .hamburger,
  .contact,
  .desktop-nav,
  .sidebar-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

body.nav-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  @media @tablet-up {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

body:not(.nav-position-sidebar),
body.nav-position-top,
body.nav-position-top-right {
  @media @tablet-up {
    .header {
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px 40px;
      border-bottom: none;
      .transition(~'padding 280ms ease');

      .container {
        display: table;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        .transition(~'height 280ms ease');
      }

      .logo {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        max-height: 80px;
        overflow: hidden;

        a {
          padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
        }
      }

      .desktop-nav {
        display: table-cell;
      }

      .nav {
        li {
          display: inline-block;
        }

        a {
          padding: 10px 20px;
        }
      }

      .membership-cart {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 5%;
        text-align: right;
        white-space: nowrap;

        span {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      }
    }

    &.collapse {
      .header {
        padding: 5px 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid fade(@fill, 5);

        .container {
          height: 40px;
        }
      }
    }

    &.full-width-nav-off .header .container {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 40px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  }
}

body.nav-position-top-right {
  .desktop-nav {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

.stuck {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
}

body.nav-position-sidebar {

  @media @tablet-up {
    .header {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 260px;
      min-height: 100vh;
      padding: 40px;
      border-bottom: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;

      > .nav-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: calc(~'100vh - 80px');
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        > .container {
          flex: 1 0 auto;
        }
      }

      .sidebar-nav {
        display: block;
      }

      .nav {
        li {
          display: block;
        }

        a {
          display: block;
          padding: 10px 0;
        }
      }

      .logo {
        margin: 0 auto 30px;
      }

      .membership-cart > span {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    .contact {
      display: block;
    }

    .wsite-phone {
      display: block;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: fade(@fill, 40);
      padding: 40px 0 0;
      text-align: left;

      &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        border-top: 1px solid fade(@fill, 20);
      }
    }

    .wrapper {
      background: @bg;
      padding-left: 260px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  }
}

.logo {
  * {
    display: block;
  }

  a {
    color: @primary;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
      background: transparent;
      .transition(opacity 200ms ease);
    }
  }

  #wsite-title {
    font-family: @font1;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  }

  img {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 70px;
  }

  .wsite-logo {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 70px;
  }
}

/* Nav */

.nav {
  vertical-align: middle;

  a {
    display: block;
    color: @fill;
    font-family: @font1;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-transform: lowercase;

    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
      background: transparent;
      .transition(opacity 200ms ease);
    }
  }

  .active {
    color: darken(@primary, 10%) !important;
  }

  #wsite-nav-cart-a {
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  #wsite-nav-cart-num {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: mix(@primary, @bg, 60%);
    color: @fill;
    min-width: 25px;
    padding: 7px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 2;

    @media @tablet-up {
      margin: 0 -6px;
    }
  }
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

/* Subnav */

#wsite-menus {
  > .wsite-menu-wrap {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  > .wsite-menu-wrap > .wsite-menu .wsite-menu {
    margin: 0 -1px;
  }

  .wsite-menu {
    position: relative;
    background: @bg;
    .box-shadow(inset 0px 0px 0px 1px fade(@fill, 3));

    li a {
      padding: 12px 20px;
      background: transparent;
      color: @fill;
      font-family: @font1;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
      border: none;

      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
        background: transparent;
        .transition(opacity 200ms ease);
      }
    }
  }

  .wsite-menu-arrow {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Sidebar and Mobile Subnav */

.sidebar-nav,
.mobile-nav {
  li {
    position: relative;
    border-color: fade(@fill, 80);
  }

  .wsite-menu {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: fade(@fill, 50);
    border-color: fade(@fill, 50);

    a {
      color: fade(@fill, 50);
    }
  }

  .wsite-menu-wrap {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    .transition(all 600ms ease-in-out);
  }

  .wsite-menu-wrap li.wsite-nav-current > a.wsite-menu-subitem {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
    border: none;
  }

  .wsite-menu-wrap .wsite-menu-arrow {
    display: none;
  }

  .dropdown {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

    &:hover {
      .icon-caret {
        opacity: 0.6;
        background: transparent;
      }
    }

    > .icon-caret,
    > .dropdown-link {
      display: table-cell !important;
      vertical-align: top;

      a {
        display: inline-block !important;
      }
    }

    .icon-caret {
      width: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      .transition(all 200ms ease-in-out);

      &:before {
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        border: solid transparent;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
        border-color: inherit;
        .transform(~'rotate(45deg)');
      }
    }

    &.open span.icon-caret:before {
      top: 5px;
      .transform(~'rotate(-135deg)');
    }

    &.open + .wsite-menu-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 1000px;
    }
  }
}

.sidebar-nav {
  .has-submenu > .dropdown span.icon-caret {
    padding: 12px 0 8px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body class="no-header-page">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="nav-wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="hamburger" aria-label="Menu" href="#"><span></span></a>
        <div class="logo">{logo}</div>
        <div class="nav desktop-nav">{menu}</div>
        <div class="nav sidebar-nav"><div class="nav-wrap">{menu}</div></div>
        <div class="nav membership-cart">{membership}{minicart}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav contact">{phone:text}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-wrap">
      {{#sections}}
          <div class="container">{content}</div>
      {{/sections}}
    </div>

    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav mobile-nav">
    <a class="hamburger" aria-label="Menu" href="#"><span></span></a>
    {menu}
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/plugins.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have to provide code , no one can help you without seeing the code

Comment: Understood, I've updated the post to include code.

Comment: there seems to be an error in your javascript  , or it's nto the entire code , you have have tried to insert some variables in HTML, but that's not how you can insert variables in HTML , unless you are using a template rendering ?

Comment: I have no idea. It's a pre-built site, so I'm not seven sure what a "template rendering" is. There's a second JavaScript file, I can try providing that.

Comment: maybe you can provide some screen shots of your issue , because the code snippet output is broken , i am trying to help , but i have no clue on your problem yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason not all elements are showing is because of this:

```
.sidebar-nav .dropdown.open + .wsite-menu-wrap, .mobile-nav .dropdown.open + .wsite-menu-wrap {  
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 1000px;   
}
```

The element is expanded by changing the `max-height` from 0px to `1000px`. The elements in your menu exceed `1000px` and they get cut off.

This is actually a pretty comman problem when using CSS transitions to expand elements. CSS transitions only work on `height` if height is set to an exact value. You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

The `max-height` trick offers a work-around. But it has its draw-back - if the elements expands beyond the value of `max-height` it gets cut off.

The simplest solution is to simply increase the value of `max-height`, until all your elements show. This will work, but it' s not ideal if in the future the element expands even more.

More sophisticated (and arguably better) solutions can be found in the css-tricks web page above.

Still, are you sure it's a good idea do display such an enormous amount of of links in an accordion menu? Wouldn't it be better to rethink the navigation, perhaps have a separate page with all the books?

Comment: Yeah. I'm really starting to think that's going to be the better case. I do appreciate the answers and help both you and BrightFaith have provided. :)